# Troubleshooting Wi-Fi not working in laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, troubleshooting

Wi-Fi stopped working abruptly (was working fine previously) while using Dell Inspiron 5548 laptop. It has Intel AC-3160 Wi-Fi card originally.

1. I dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 18.10. It doesn't work in either.
2. In Ubuntu it just shows that Wi-Fi is off and 'turn on' button does nothing. In Windows device information shows that device is working properly, but it shows no networks around.
3. There's Bluetooth on the very same Intel AC-3160 card and it works fine.
4. I tried inserting Intel AC-8265 Wi-Fi card (should be compatible with my laptop), but it produces exact same results.

I am sure that's not enough information, but the main reason I am writing here is to get some troubleshooting tips, as I am not sure how to find out the exact problem.

**Edit:**

I managed to turn on Wi-Fi interface via terminal on Ubuntu (still says off in UI though) and it can even scan for networks around. I've actually already bought USB Wi-Fi adapter, and while it works on Windows, it behaves similarly to integrated card on Ubuntu (can't turn on through UI, but can turn on and scan for networks in terminal)(I've installed drivers for USB adapter)

Comment: *It doesn't work in either* means hardware problem. Either the card or the motherboard's connector. That another card doesn't work seems to confirm the latter (but it's also possible that the new one isn't "whitelisted" in BIOS/UEFI).

Comment: Try reseating the card. Make sure the antenna connections are seated properly.

Comment: I've edited the post.

Comment: How are the hinges looking in this laptop? Are they damaged?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart nope. And it wasn't dropped, it stopped working when I was just using it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by turning off airplane mode (fn + prtscreen on my laptop). What's strange that there was absolutely no indication neither in Windows nor Ubuntu, that it was turned on.

Comment: 4 years later, you just ended a very frustrating afternoon! No chance I would have solved this otherwise, thank you